# W3C validation errors

Tags: html, validation, drupal

I am getting several validation errors regarding a website using drupal, coming from this section of the page:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr"
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
xmlns:sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#"
xmlns:sioct="http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#"
xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
<head>
```

The following validation errors:

```
Line 11, Column 48: Attribute xmlns:content not allowed here.
Line 11, Column 48: Attribute xmlns:dc not allowed here
Line 11, Column 48: Attribute xmlns:foaf not allowed here.
Line 11, Column 48: Attribute xmlns:og not allowed here.
Line 11, Column 48: Attribute xmlns:rdfs not allowed here.
```

etc....

Anyone ever experience this with drupal or any other site?

Comment: You should specify which HTML version you are validating against.

Comment: HTML5 but it looks like the page is using some xml

Answer (score 2):

From the symptoms, it seems that you are validating against HTML5, probably using `<!DOCTYPE html>`. The W3C validator validates against the rules of HTML serialization (HTML syntax), where attributes like `xmlns:content` are invalid. There is no namespace concept, so any `:` in an attribute name is just yet another character with no special meaning, and such names have not been defined.

Using http://validator.nu/ you can select, in the “Preset” dropdown, XML serialization of HTML5, known as XHTML5. Then you need to follow all XML rules as well as HTML5 rules, and you need to include the attribute `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` in the `<html>` tag.